# Javascript is not able to access Html Form data though populated

Tags: javascript, html

Below is my HTML and Javascipt code. My Javascript code is not able to access my HTML form data
compose-recipients though it is populated. compose-recipients always returns an empty string.

**HTML File**

```
  <div id="compose-view">
        <h3>New Email</h3>
        <form id="compose-form">
            <div class="form-group">
                From: <input disabled class="form-control" value="{{ request.user.email }}">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                To: <input id="compose-recipients" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" id="compose-subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="compose-body" placeholder="Body"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" id="submit-button"/>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
document.querySelector('#submit-button').addEventListener('click', send_email);


function send_email() {

// The return value is an empty string though it is populated in the form
console.log(document.querySelector('#compose-recipients').value);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('#submit-button')` can't find any elements, because it is executed at the start of your JS file, when the document isn't initialized yet. You can use `window.onload = () => document.querySelector('#submit-button').addEventListener('click', send_email);` to register the event listener when the window is loaded.

Edit: [MDN Docs link for window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)